# new vs object create giving different results OO javascript

Tags: javascript, oop, constructor, object-literal

I'm working with a data object lit, then trying to create a new object that changes properties in the data property just for that instance, here's some test code from jsbin

```
data = {
  innerData : 1 
}

-------------

'This works :-)'

construct = function(d){
  this.data = Object.create(d);
};

construct.prototype.c = function(n){
  this.data.innerData  =  n;
};

construct.prototype.d = function(){
   console.log(this.data.innerData)
};

--------------

'This does not :-{'

construct = {
  data : Object.create(data),
  changeData : function(n){
    this.data.innerData  =  n;
  },
  showData:function(){
    console.log(this.data.innerData)
  }
}

--------------

newInst = Object.create(construct);
newInst.changeData(5);
newInst.showData();

newInst2 = Object.create(construct);
newInst2showData();
```

when I run it using the constructor/prototype functions it works and the console outputs 5,2

when I run it using the object literal the console outputs 5,5 I guess when I create the first instance it changes the actual data object and not the data property of the  instance of the construct object.

If someone could explain in depth why this happens that would be much help as I've not been working with OOJS for that long

**UPDATE:**

so I had a little go at merging what I found useful from the answers and I've come up with this....

```
data = {
  innerData : 1 
}

function construct(d){
  return {
    data : Object.create(d),
    changeData : function(n){
      this.data.innerData  =  n;
    },
    showData : function(){
      console.log(this.data.innerData)
    }
  }
}

build = function(){
 return(new construct(data));
}

newInst = build();
newInst.changeData(5);
newInst.showData();

newInst2 = build();
newInst2.showData();
```

Comment: Arrays are passed by reference and not copied.

Comment: @zerkms What arrays? :)

Comment: @Jack: ooops, objects. Who counts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your second example, there is only ever one `data` object. That object lives inside `construct` and is available to all the subsequent objects on the prototype chain.

In your first example, you make a new `data` object every time a new instance is created. So each object gets its own copy of `data`.

Try this, for the first example:

```
console.log(newInst.data === newInst2.data); // should be false
```

and for the second example:

```
console.log(newInst.data === newInst2.data); // should be true
```

Comment: So is there no way to make a new copy of data in the second example?

Comment: Yeah, there are several ways. The most convenient way is probably to use a constructor function, which is what your first example uses. You could also create a factory function that spits out new objects.

Comment: ok I get it, I had thought it was somewhere along those lines but couldn't quite figure it out and thought I didn't need the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Given what we know about the inheritance, what does the following actually do

```
this.data.innerData  =  n;
```

where `this` is the result of `Object.create(construct)`?

1. `this` does not have own property `data`, so look up in the inherited properties.
2. Okay we found a `data === Object.getPrototypeOf(this).data`, call it `d`
3. Next set `innerData` of `d` to `n`

So what the actual result has ended up is the `innerData` property has been set on the reference from the *prototype*, and not a new *Object*.

Why has this happened? Because if you have `o = {}` and try to do `o.foo.bar`, you get a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'bar' of undefined`, and therefore for it to not throw an error, it has to be accessing a *defined Object*.

```
var proto = {foo: {bar: 'fizz'}},
    obj = Object.create(proto);
obj.foo.bar = 'buzz';
proto.foo.bar; // "buzz" (i.e. NOT "fizz" anymore)
// and
obj.foo === Object.getPrototypeOf(obj).foo; // true
```

Answer (score 0):

The second piece of code works just fine:

```
construct.changeData(2);
construct.showData(); // 2
```

The only difference is that in the above example `construct` is not a constructor, so there will be only a single instance of `construct.data` as opposed to the first approach; calling `Object.create()` on it will create a new object but will keep the same `.data` reference as the first.

Comment: Thank's for the answer. Matt's made a little more sense straight off but +1

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an attempt to create a factory function instead of a constructor function.  Since `Object.create` is now widespread, and shimmable for these purposes where not available, this has become perhaps the best default, although there are plenty of constructor functions still around.

Some of the other answers explain what went wrong with your attempt.  Here's how you might do it so that it works as expected:

```
var factory = (function() {
  var clone = function(obj) {return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));};
  var data = {
    innerData : 1 
  };

  var proto = {
    changeData : function(n){
      this.data.innerData = n;
    },
    showData:function(){
      console.log(this.data.innerData)
    }
  };

  return function() {
    var obj = Object.create(proto);
    obj.data = clone(data);
    return obj;
  }
}());
```

---

But it looks as though your `innerData` might have been an experiment to try to get these things working.  It it's not necessary, this would be cleaner:

```
var factory = (function() {
  var proto = {
    data: 1,
    changeData : function(n){
      this.data = n;
    },
    showData:function(){
      console.log(this.data)
    }
  };

  return function() {
    return Object.create(proto);
  }
}());
```

Comment: Your clone method assumes that there exists a standard _JSON_ representation of the _JavaScript Object_, which might not be the case.

Comment: I need IE7 support unfortunately and that means adding another file :-(, I did try a different clone method originally that worked in IE7. I do like your idea as a concept though

Comment: @PaulS.: Yes, this `clone` was entirely naive, mostly because I was hoping it could be thrown away altogether in favor of the second version.

Comment: @OliMillington: I would hope that something more like the second version would be more helpful, but it's quite possible that your `data` object is too complex for that.